# Get high resolution for bitmap fonts under pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, resolution

I’m using the [Boisik](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/boisik) font/package, which is not available as Type 1 and so (unless I’ve missed something) is only able to produce bitmapped fonts in the pdf output.  By default, the resolution of these is fairly low.

Using a `latex` → `dvips` → `ps2pdf` workflow, I can at least make sure the generated bitmaps are high resolution, by invoking `dvips` with an option like `dvips -D 2400` (as suggested in the Boisik documentation).

Is there any way to do this while using `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameter to set is `\pdfpkresolution` that TeX Live (and MiKTeX, I believe) sets to 600 (dpi).

It can be set in the document by

```
\pdfpkresolution=2400
```

There is also a token register `\pdfpkmode` that chooses the Metafont mode for creating the bitmaps, if non empty:

```
\pdfpkmode={supre}
```

The `supre` mode is found in `modes.mf` and is for a 2400 dpi printer (but it may be not the right one for yours.