# renderize yfonts without the pixels signs

Tags: fonts, drop-cap, resolution

how can i renderize this initials without the pixels signs but like the normal font?

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/baroqueinitials/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, these fonts are not available as Type 1 fonts.  This means that they are rendered as bitmaps with the current bitmap resolution.

To increase the quality of the fonts, increase the resolution.  For `pdflatex` this is explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34177/get-high-resolution-for-bitmap-fonts-under-pdflatex): add to the preamble

```
\pdfpkresolution=2400
\pdfpkmode={supre}
```