# Is it possible to manually alias the bbm blackboard fonts?

Tags: fonts, blackboard, pixelated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get high resolution for bitmap fonts under pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34177/get-high-resolution-for-bitmap-fonts-under-pdflatex)

I am using the command `\mathbbm` from the `bbm` package and I have realized that this fonts are pixelated when I generate my pdf with `pdftex`. The issue is that this fonts are bitmap fonts, and, after some search, no vector version of them seems to be available.

The **question** is, is there a way in LaTeX to control how much a bitmap font is aliased? In other words, can I make these fonts look more smooth, even if they are bitmaps?

I tried to look for a solution similar to this [post's](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18747/polutonikogreek-with-lmodern-12pt&ei=mpt0ULq6CNHEsgbk5oHYCA&usg=AFQjCNHiy8xRUCVYq6t_z16pRR9U3G9u4Q), where the OP had a problem with pixelated greek characters, yet it did not work.

Another "solution" is to use other packages, but yet I do not know another type of blackboard fonts that looks 'good' together with `computer modern` (or `latin modern`) and that it is supported in MiKTex/TexLive (this is important to me for compatibility reasons with my coworkers): examples that look bad are `bbold`, `txfonts` and `mathpazo`.

Comment: Bitmap fonts are created at a default resolution of 600dpi. You can modify it by saying `\pdfpkresolution=1200` or some other number that suits your needs.

Comment: That solves the problem. Actually, thanks to you I found this [post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34177/get-high-resolution-for-bitmap-fonts-under-pdflatex/34178#34178), where they solve essentially the same problem. I guess we can close this question as duplicated and refer to the other one.

Comment: A pity that your first question is a duplicate, but don't worry: also duplicate questions may help readers to find their way here. I *should* have known that answer. `;-)`

Comment: Actually it's not difficult to run `mftrace` on the bbm files.