# How to use T4 fonts in LaTex?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, tipa

I would like to input some African language symbols (`\B{t}`, `\m{y}`). I tried command:

```
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}
```

But it did not work. How can I use T4 font encoding?

Comment: [This example](http://hastebin.com/luputeheqe.tex) works just [fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DTQUl.png) for me.

Comment: With a UTF-8 engine (xetex, luatex) you [directly input](http://hastebin.com/olosesizum.tex) the characters.  You just have to load a font which contains them (e.g. [CMU Serif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/snVhe.png)).

Comment: Unfortunately, 'it did not work' is just about the [most unhelpful](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) description of a problem one can imagine. What code did you use? (That line alone will never work by itself.) What happened? What didn't happen?  What error or warning messages did you receive? The answers to any and all of these questions would be enlightening. And in the *TeX world, a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is crucial 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want some symbols or words using the T4 encoding, you can do with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\AS}[1]{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont#1}}

\begin{document}

\AS{\B{t}} \AS{\m{y}}

\end{document}
```

If you need an environment form, add

```
\newenvironment{tfour}{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont}{}
```

and do

```
\begin{tfour}\B{t} \m{y}\end{tfour}
```

Note, however, that T4 encoded fonts are only available as bitmap, so the output will be quite jagged, unless you instruct `pdftex` to use higher resolution than the default 600dpi.

[image]

You can choose higher resolution like in [Get high resolution for bitmap fonts under pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34177/get-high-resolution-for-bitmap-fonts-under-pdflatex)

```
\pdfpkmode{supre} \pdfpkresolution=2400

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T4,T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\AS}[1]{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont#1}}

\begin{document}

\AS{\B{t}} \AS{\m{y}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even better resolution can be obtained with

```
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz} \pdfpkresolution=8000
```

(but the PDF file will be huge).

[image]